# R - How to select dominant b1-value and count(b2) and make b2 values column headings

Tags: r

Sample data:

```
a <- as.data.frame(matrix(list(1,1,3,4,1,1,3,4,1,1,3,4,1,1,3,4,1,1,3,4),4,5)) 
b1 <-c(30,40,20,15) b2<-c("A","A","B","C")
b <-as.data.frame(cbind(b1,b2)) 
a.b<-cbind(a,b)
```

Inital value:
`a.b`

```
    row V1 V2 V3 V4 V5 b1 b2
    1  1  1  1  1  1 30  A
    2  1  1  1  1  1 40  A
    3  3  3  3  3  3 20  B
    4  4  4  4  4  4 15  C
```

What I would like to see would be V1, V2, V3, V4, V5, b1 with the max(b1), A, B, C
there should be 3 rows:

```
    row V1 V2 V3 V4 V5 b1 A B C
    1  1  1  1  1  1 40  2  0 0 
    3  3  3  3  3  3 20  0  1 0
    4  4  4  4  4  4 15  0  0 1
```

How would I go about getting that.  I have thought of aggregate, cast, and reshape, but have run into difficulty.  Thks.

Comment: Never use as.data.frame(cbind(...)). In your case it made everything as "character".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This looks like an lapply(split(...)) problem. Untested and assumes you do NOT use as.data.frame(cbind(...))

```
lapply(split(df, df[2:6]), function (d){
                    cbind( max( d[7]), table(d[8]) )})
```

The reason to not use character comparison is that "4" > "15" returns TRUE.

Comment: Thks, could you be more specific about the function.  I used a.b in place of df but didn't know what to use in the function call.  An error was generated.Error in sort.list(y) : 'x' must be atomic for 'sort.list'

Comment: Sorry. Traveling w/o access to R interpreter on iPhone. Unable to so any testing.

Answer (score 0):

This is not trivial.

Here is my way to do it, it is far from perfect but it should be enough to get you started:

```
first_part = aggregate(a.b[,1:6],by=list(a.b$b2),
              function(x) {y=as.factor(unlist(x));max(as.numeric(levels(y))[y])})
second_part = diag(by(a.b$b2,a.b$b2,function(x)length(x)))
colnames(second_part) = first_part[,1]
all = cbind(first_part[2:7], second_part)
```

It does the job:

```
> all
  V1 V2 V3 V4 V5 b1 A B C
1  1  1  1  1  1 40 2 0 0
2  3  3  3  3  3 20 0 1 0
3  4  4  4  4  4 15 0 0 1
```

*Explanation of how it works:*

The first line constructs the first part of the matrix: keeping the rows with the max value for b1.

```
> first_part
  Group.1 V1 V2 V3 V4 V5 b1
1       A  1  1  1  1  1 40
2       B  3  3  3  3  3 20
3       C  4  4  4  4  4 15
```

**"warning!"** this is were this method is so-so: it applies the max function over all elements in all rows with the same letter. But you did not specify what to do in case the values in V1...V5 are different.

The second and third lines construct the second part of the matrix:

```
     A B C
[1,] 2 0 0
[2,] 0 1 0
[3,] 0 0 1
```

Overall, I am sure there are better and cleaner way to do it. Please comment if you see a possible amelioration, I am always glad to learn something new :)

Comment: Thanks for your response.  V1 and V2 represent sites, and V3 thru V5 are FACTORS so they can be different.  b1 is a percent and b2 represents species.

Comment: @slideag: then how do you want to handle the case where V3 through V5 are different for the same letter?

Comment: When V1 thru V5 are the same the count for 1 species is incremented.  When they are different the count for one of the species will be 1 for the others it will be 0.  Hope that explains sufficiently.  Thks.

Comment: Then I am unsure how to do it. Have you tried @IShouldBuyABoat's solution?

Comment: I attempted IShouldBuyABoat's solution and but had difficulty translating it to my example.